# Phonegap: Access Phonegap API in remote HTML page

Tags: android, iframe, webview, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to call phonegap API (e.g. Camera, File API) in remote HTML page (http://xxx.com) using Worklight.
I have tried to use (1) iFrame and (2) embed in WebView.

**(1) iFrame**

`<iframe src="http://xxx.com"></iframe>`

After googling for a while, it is said that it will not be successful because of same origin policy. Instead it can be achieved by HTML postMessage. I have done a simple test and it works. 
But since for my use case, I would like to perform a file upload in remote HTML page. After capturing a photo using camera API, I got a FILE_URI / DATA_URI. It was not possible for me to upload the file in remote HTML page apart from using File API there. Therefore, my goal is to call phonegap API directly in remote page and here comes to my next step.

**(2) embed in WebView**

I have tried to add `webview.loadUrl("http://xxx.com")` in Android native code

```
public class TestActivity extends DroidGap {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.xxx.com");
    }
}
```

In my remote HTML page, I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("OK!");
    }
</script>
```

to test if the phonegap API is ready to be used.

However, onDeviceReady is never fired.

Is there something wrong here? Or is it possible to access phonegap API in remote HTML page which is embedded in webview?

Comment: Hi,have you ever find solution with embeded WebViews ??

Answer (score 0):

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);